# How to properly make migrations when adding a new unique field

Tags: django, django-migrations

I added a new field to one of my models:

```
class Agency(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name=_("e-mail"))
```

As this field cannot be blank, `django-admin makemigrations` requested me to provide one-off default, which I did. Here is the generated migration:

```
# Generated by Django 1.9.4 on 2016-03-20 10:38
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0008_auto_20160226_1226'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='agency',
            name='email',
            field=models.EmailField(default='example@example.fr', max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='e-mail'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

As expected, `django-admin migrate` throwed an error:

```
psycopg2.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "accounts_agency_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(example@example.fr) is duplicate.
```

I thought I could edit the migration to set unique values before making the field unique. So I tried:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.4 on 2016-03-20 10:38
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
from django.utils.text import slugify


def set_email(apps, schema_editor):
    Agency = apps.get_model('accounts', 'Agency')
    for agency in Agency.objects.all():
        agency.email = '{}@example.fr'.format(slugify(agency.name))
        agency.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0008_auto_20160226_1226'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='agency',
            name='email',
            field=models.EmailField(default='', max_length=254, blank=True, verbose_name='e-mail'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(set_email),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='agency',
            name='email',
            field=models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='e-mail'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Unfortunately I get this error when running `django-admin migrate`:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE "accounts_agency" because it has pending trigger events
```

My guess is that `operations` are not executed synchronously.

I think I could fix the issue by splitting the migration into two migrations, but I'd like to know if I can do it in only one migration. What is the common way to create migrations when adding a new unique field in a model?

PS: I also tried to use an F expression as default (`default=models.F('name') + '@example.fr'`) but it failed:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "accounts_agency_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(F(name) + Vallu(@example.fr)) is duplicated.
```

Comment: Have you read the section of docs that deals with exactly this problem? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields

Comment: @koniiiik, I search on the wrong page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/  So, looks like there is no way to get it work with only one migration.

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not want to use two migrations?

Comment: Not especially, it was just about curiosity.

Comment: I was surprised that doing all operations in the same migration didn't work. However, having 2 (or 3) migrations  means that, by mistake, one could be reverted without the others, which would put the application in an unexpected state.

Comment: I wrote a [pull request 9212](https://github.com/django/django/pull/9212) to Django howto, inspired by this question, to simplify it and especially to prevent the "unexpected state". Currently I'm waiting.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's too late but maybe it could work for someone else

You can do this in one migration via using **migrations.RunSQL** method

For your example code after you added the new field to your model and run the **python manage.py makemigrations** command (here if you have existing rows in your table command wants to choice default value you can choice *"Provide a one-off default now"* option and give some string value it is not important because actually we did not use it) then go to migration file and change operations part with this (Note i use postgresql you can change SQL for your database)

```
operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
        'ALTER TABLE "agency" ADD COLUMN "email" varchar(254) NULL;ALTER TABLE "agency" ALTER COLUMN "email" DROP DEFAULT;COMMIT;',
        ),
        migrations.RunSQL(
        "UPDATE agency SET email= Concat(country_code, '@example.fr');COMMIT;",
        ),
        migrations.RunSQL(
        'ALTER TABLE "agency" ALTER COLUMN "email" SET NOT NULL;ALTER TABLE "agency" ADD CONSTRAINT "agency_email_b551ad2a_uniq" UNIQUE ("email");ALTER TABLE "agency" ALTER COLUMN "email" DROP DEFAULT;CREATE INDEX "agency_email_b551ad2a_like" ON "agency" ("email" varchar_pattern_ops);COMMIT;'
        )
    ]
```

then run "**python manage.py migrate**" command
that is it.

Comment: This was awesome. Thanks very much